# pipe()-ing programs causes EIO

Tags: c, unix, pipe, ioerror

We have a homework question where we have to write a program that takes two arguments, executes them as shell commands pipeing the stdout of the first program into the stdin of the second program.

This is my [solution](http://fuz.su/~fuz/mypipe.c) to this homework question. The same file is reproduced below.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHELL   "/bin/sh"

extern int  main(int, char*[]);
static int  readingend(int, int, const char*);
static int  writingend(int, int, const char*);
static int  usr1handler();

extern int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pipefd[2], status;
    pid_t rpid, wpid;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument count\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pipe(pipefd)) {
        perror("Cannot make a pipe");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    signal(SIGUSR1, (void(*)(int))usr1handler);

    if ((rpid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Cannot fork");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (rpid == 0)
        return (readingend(pipefd[0], pipefd[1], argv[2]));


    if ((wpid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Cannot fork");
        kill(rpid, SIGKILL);
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (wpid == 0)
        return (writingend(pipefd[0], pipefd[1], argv[1]));

    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    waitpid(rpid, &status, 0);
    return (status);
}

static int
readingend(int rfd, int wfd, const char *cmd)
{
    close(wfd);
    dup2(rfd, STDIN_FILENO);

    /* execl() only returns on error */
    execl(SHELL, SHELL, "-c", cmd, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute %s: ", cmd);
    perror(NULL);

    /* clean up */
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static int
writingend(int rfd, int wfd, const char *cmd)
{
    close(rfd);
    dup2(wfd, STDOUT_FILENO);

    execl(SHELL, SHELL, "-c", cmd, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute %s: ", cmd);
    perror(NULL);

    /* clean up */
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static int
usr1handler()
{
    /* child already printed diagnostic */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The problem is that in some invocations, the first process receives an `EIO` upon reading from stdin. This seems to happen only on some shells: It happens with `ksh93` and `bash` but not with `bosh`. Such an error looks like this:

```
$ LANG=C ./mypipe cat true
$ cat: -: Input/output error
```

Can anybody tell me why this error occurs? What can I do to have that error not occur anymore? Clearly there must be a way as executing `cat | true` in an ordinary shell produces the desired result without any spurious `EIO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because `true` instantly terminates, causing `mypipe` to terminate, too, leaving `cat` orphaned. If this happens, `read()` may fail:

> #### EIO
>
> The process is a member of a background process attempting to read from its  controlling  terminal,  the  process is ignoring or blocking the `SIGTTIN` signal, or the process group is orphaned. This error may also be generated for implementation-defined reasons.

This issue can be prevented by waiting on both processes like this:

```
extern int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status, estatus;

    /* ... */


    /* wait for both processes to terminate */
    if (wait(&status) == rpid) {
        estatus = status;
        wait(&status);
    } else {
        wait(&status);
        estatus = status;
    }

    return (estatus);
}
```